# Upstart how to autostart a job after MySQL startup at boot time?

Tags: upstart

My job is dependent on MySQL. So I want my job could startup after MySQL.

I read the [upstart cookbook](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#order-in-which-jobs-which-start-on-the-same-event-are-run) and I find `start on` can auto start a job.

```
start on started mysql
```

And it works. But I don't want mysql will affect my job after boot. When I stop my job, it will be restarted by restarting mysql.
How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lock file in `/tmp/` folder to track that your job already run. Here an example:

1. Create these two upstart jobs configuration files:

   `/etc/init/joba.conf`

   ```
   # job A

   start on local-filesystems
   stop on runlevel[016]

   script
     /bin/echo job-A started >> /tmp/myjobs.log
     exec sleep 5
   end script
   ```

   `/etc/init/jobb.conf`

   ```
   # job B triggered after A

   start on started joba

   script
     /bin/echo job-B started >> /tmp/myjobs.log
     if ! [ -f /tmp/jobb.lock ]
     then
       /bin/echo " do job-B tasks" >> /tmp/myjobs.log
       /bin/touch /tmp/jobb.lock
     else
       /bin/echo " bypass job-B tasks"  >> /tmp/myjobs.log
     fi
     exec sleep 5
   end script
   ```
2. Reboot
3. Check `cat /tmp/myjobs.log` or open `sudo tail -f /tmp/myjobs.log` in another window.
4. Try run job-A again `sudo start joba`
5. Check `/tmp/myjobs.log`, see bypass note:

   ```
   job-A started
   job-B started
    do job-B tasks
   job-B started
    bypass job-B tasks
   job-A started
   job-B started
   job-A started
    bypass job-B tasks
   ```

**Note:** For each run, we have 3 lines. It does not matter lines sorting here. `stdout` buffering issue, it is not related to upstart. The jobs are run in the correct sequence.